# Importing strings to Scheme without using open-input-string

Tags: string, input, scheme, racket

I am trying to have my Scheme program import strings without needing to use open-input-string before the string. So for example, right now I can do the following:

```
> (scheme_lexer (open-input-string "3+4*2"))
```

However, is there a way for my program to work if I input the string this way?:

```
> (scheme_lexer ("3+4*2"))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you can't just make a `scheme_lexer_string` function that does this for you when dealing with strings? The extra parentheses just seem like clutter, and they make a macro the only real solution. If you dropped that requirement and made something like `(scheme_lexer "3+4*2")` acceptable, you can make an ordinary function for handling strings:

```
(define (scheme_lexer_string s)
  (scheme_lexer (open-input-string s)))
```

If what you want is a function that handles both input ports and strings, you can make a general function that dispatches based on the type of the argument to the specific functions. In this case, your original `scheme_lexer` would be renamed to `scheme_lexer_input_port` and you would have these functions:

```
(define (scheme_lexer_string s)
  (scheme_lexer_input_port (open-input-string s)))

(define (scheme_lexer in)
  (if (string? in)
      (scheme_lexer_string in)
      (scheme_lexer_input_port in)))
```

Now `scheme_lexer` works for both strings and ports and dispatches to the correct function as desired.

```
> (scheme_lexer some-input-port)
... evaluates the content in the port
> (scheme_lexer "abcd")
... evaluates the string "abcd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option. I have used a testing function `lexer` just to show the macro. You can adjust it to your needs.

```
(define (lexer sp) (read sp))

(define-syntax scheme_lexer
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (input))
     (lexer (open-input-string input)))))
```

And to test:

```
> (scheme_lexer ("3+4*2"))
'3+4*2
```